# Отображение одних объектов относительно других

Tags: java

Есть персонаж и список с объектами, как сделать так, чтобы одни объекты отображались на переднем плане, а другие позади персонажа?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 5):

Банально рисовать объекты заднего плана раньше, чем переднего =)

Comment: Это будет правильным решением или есть более "умные" методы?

Comment: andrei561, это будет правильным решением. Заводишь глубину для объектов и рисуешь начиная с самого дальнего.

Comment: Есть "умный" метод - т.н. метод трассировки лучей. То есть как бы строишь луч от точки объекта до глаза наблюдателя, если по пути луча есть препятствие точка невидима. В данном случае это бессмысленно - слишком примитивные объекты. Трассировка лучей имеет смысл для 3D визуализации да и то когда рендеринг каждой точки занимает много времени.

Comment: @andrei561
Для вашего примера это самый умный способ. Как правильно заметил @Barmaley, можно высчитывать перекрытие слоев, определять видимые части и отображать только их. Но это имеет смысл в случае большого количества накладывающихся слоев и/или дорогой операции вывода. Но в данном случае дважды пройтись по тем же пикселам скорее всего дешевле и уж точно проще реализуемо.

"Преждевременная оптимизация — корень всех зол."